# addClass not working in the project

Tags: javascript, addclass

I'm trying to change menu bg on scroll and I'm stuck here. "addClass" just doesn't apply. I have smt like this:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

nav.scrolling {
    background-color: #424242;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $("nav").addClass("scrolling");
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("scrolling");
    }
});
```

It's working on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xSe4/5/), but doesn't in my project.

Comment: What does the console say when you scroll? Are you adding the JS files at the end of the body?

Comment: pay attention **$('nav')**,

Comment: Are you calling your DOM dependent code after it's [ready](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)?

Comment: I tried to include JS code in <head>, before and after <nav> in the body. Nothing's happen. Console doesn't saying anything too.

Comment: are you sure the height of your document allows scrolling more than 500px?

Comment: The page allows scrolling more than 5000px)

Comment: Are you sure the $(window).scroll function is working? Maybe try adding a console.log(scroll) to check what the value of scroll is? I tried your code and it works for me locally.

Comment: Try adding a `$(document).ready()` around your script.

Comment: Console output: console.log(scroll)
function scroll() { [native code] }
undefined. Nothing's changed after adding "$(document).ready()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was in the

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```